# Simple Laravel where query fails to run

Tags: php, laravel, search, eloquent

I'm trying to implement a passable search for my web app and decided to follow along with the Laracasts video [here](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch/episodes/37).

This is the form where the request is made:

```xml
<form action="find-manufacturer/" class="search-form" method="GET">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search for your manufacturer" name="search" id="search" autocomplete="off" value="{{ request("search") }}"> 
</form>
```

The route that handles the request:

```php
Route::get("find-manufacturer/", function (Manufacturer $manufacturer) {
    if (request("search")) {
        $manufacturers = Manufacturer::where('slug', 'like', '%' . request("search") . '%')->get();

        return view("search-results", [
            "manufacturer" => $manufacturer,  // This variable is irrelevant to the current problem, but doesn't seem to be causing a conflict either                                               
            "manufacturers" => $manufacturers, 
        ]);
    }
});
```

And finally the Blade file in which the results should be rendered:

```xml
@if($manufacturers->isNotEmpty())
    @foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer)
        {{ $manufacturer->slug }}
    @endforeach
@else
    <div>
        <p><h1>No results found.</h1></p>
    </div>
@endif
```

No matter how many valid search terms (either part or all of the record's slug) I enter in my form, the search term never returns anything, even while I'm still able to successfully return all the slugs with `Manufacturer:all()`.

I replaced `get()` with a `toSql()` for debugging and dumped it into `dd()`, the result of which seems to confirm that the problem lies in the search term:

```
"select * from `manufacturers` where `slug` like ?"
```

However, not only is the search term functionally identical to what Jeffrey Way uses in the Laracasts video, I can't get it working no matter how many variations of it with different quoting/concatting methods I try.

What's going on here?

Comment: Try `dd('%' . request("search") . '%');` to see what that contains

Comment: Looking at this, the first thing I noticed is a lack of `@csrf` anywhere on the form. Try @aynber's suggestion and see if you get a 4** error message, if so, this is the issue.

Comment: @DerickMasai The form is using GET, not POST, so CSRF isn't an issue.

Comment: @aynber It returns `"%searchterm%"`, where `searchterm` is exactly what I searched for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using any parameter, so there's no point in using route model binding

```php
Route::get("find-manufacturer/", function (Manufacturer $manufacturer) {...});
```

Also, if `request('search')` is evaluated to false, your function will not do anything. With that in mind, your route function should probably be

```php
Route::get("find-manufacturer/", function () {
    if (request("search")) {
        $manufacturers = Manufacturer::where('slug', 'like', '%' . request("search") . '%')->get();
    } else {
        $manufacturers = collect();
    }

    return view("search-results", compact('manufacturers'));
});
```

Comment: Ah, so the problem was in the logic? Weird, I was sure that the logic I was using was the same as the one in the Laracasts video. Either way tested and works perfectly. Good point about the route-model binding too, it was copy-pasted from another route that was actually using a route parameter.

Comment: I think the problem was the route model binding part, the rest (always returning something) is just my personal preference

Comment: It's actually not the route-model binding as I had to add it back in along with the `$manufacturer` variable, as I was using that variable for a dynamic route check inside of my navbar and haven't yet figured out a way to replace it. But I can confirm that even with the route-model binding and both variables present (and caches cleared) the search functionality works fine, so it was either the logic or the `collect()` that you used (and come to think of it, after hours of searching this is the first time I've ever seen it used).

Comment: `collect` just creates a `Collection` from an array. Without any parameters, it returns an empty `Collection`.